# Error in windows phone 8.1 application development using VS 2013

Tags: c#, xaml

**Error In Windows Phone 8.1 App Development: The type or namespace name 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: i already add Presentationcore.dll, but not solved, it shows that vs 2013 is composed of all by default

Answer (score 0):

Included 'ManipulationDelta' event inside xaml for a Grid(just for testing).In the code behind, following callback was written:

```
private void LayoutRoot_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but didn't gave the error as you are getting, anyways ManipulationDeltaEventArgs is there inside namespace system.windows.input, hope that is included in your c# file.